# Making XMonad redetect two monitors

Tags: xmonad, multi-monitor

I accidentally pressed Meta-Q and xmonad restarted.  Now, it has mirrored the same thing on both of my monitors.  How do I get it go back to treating them as two separate screens?

Things I have tried:

- Pressing Meta-Q again
- Turning one of the monitors off and back on

This has happened before, and logging out and back in again worked.  But I don't want to do that every time I accidentally press Meta-Q.  This has started happening since I started using dmenu_run to launch apps.  Previously, Meta-Q would restart xmonad harmlessly (without going into mirrored mode).